# I can't boot into Windows although that's my only system

Tags: windows, grub2, dual-boot

A long time ago I had Fedora installed. It's still available to boot into for some reason, but that only goes to GRUB. Now I recently set back my BIOS settings (I have a dell) and now it boots into GRUB no matter what. When I try to delete Fedora it just sets it back and goes booting in it again. Also tried just disabling it. What do I do? I don't have an USB stick right now to recover (using Windows 11 by the way)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How do I delete Fedora permanently and GRUB so it automatically boots into Windows after BIOS?